# too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python

Есть список ['a', 'b']
Почему нельзя пройтись по нему таким образом:

```
c = input().split('_') # a_b
for p, q in c:
    print(f"{p} @ {q}")
```

Как в цикле обратиться сразу к двум переменным из списка?

Comment: думаю что проще будет убрать `for` и обойтись только `print(' @ '.join(c))`

Comment: @5c0rp, это если у вас только два элемента в списке. А если товарищу действительно нужно длинющий список обрабатывать pair-wise?

Comment: @5c0rp а если нужно как-то изменить переменные, тут же print для примера написан

Comment: Дан список из двух элементов, не больше и не меньше. Здесь pair-wise не нужен

Comment: Зачем вам вообще переменные тогда, если можно читать и писать список по индексу? что-то вы нагородили себе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цикл тут не нужен, можно просто распаковать:

```
p, q = c
```

Ваш вариант не работает потому, что `for` перебирает элементы коллекции по одному, а вам нужны для присваивания сразу оба элемента списка.